# How to test whether dependency inject fails?

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring integration application and I want my flow to fail at start up if the properties provided are not correct.

For example, I have something like

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = GraphConfig.TRANSFORM_TYPE_KEY, matchIfMissing = true)
```

In my code and if this condition evaluates to true, I force a dependency injection failure at start up.

Now I want to write a test case for that. But using `@SpringBootTest` won't work, as dependency injection will fail before my test method even starts.

How can I have my test to succeed if dependency injection fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking similar like,

```
public class SpringTEst {

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    private ConfigurableEnvironment environment = new StandardEnvironment();

    @Test
    public void allPropertiesAreDefined() {
        load(MultiplePropertiesRequiredConfiguration.class, "property1=value2", "property2=value2");
        assertThat(this.context.containsBean("foo")).isTrue();
    }

    private void load(Class<?> config, String... environment) {
        TestPropertyValues.of(environment).applyTo(this.environment);
        this.context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(config).environment(this.environment).web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
                .run();
    }

    @Configuration
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = { "property1", "property2" })
    protected static class MultiplePropertiesRequiredConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public String foo() {
            return "foo";
        }

    }
}
```

Above test case will fail if you call *load* method only with *"property1=value2"* or _"property5=value2".

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to write a test case for that. But using @SpringBootTest won't work, as dependency injection will fail before my test method even starts.
>    I want my flow to fail at start up if the properties provided are not correct.

But that is the way to "check" your application context for correctness. What do you really want?
If you want your test to be green, if there are some beans are missing, then you should try to get "expected to be missing" beans from context, and assert them for null.

Comment: I want to do the opposite check. I don't want to check for missing beans, but for injection failure.